# Trying to create a collapsable gallery nav

Tags: html, gallery, nav, collapsable

I'm trying to create a gallery nav, e.g. [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdFS2.png) but I can't figure how to keep the nav items inlined-blocked and including multiple "content" elements per nav item. Here is what I have thus far:

http://jsfiddle.net/dmabuada/sv638nLv/

```
<ul class="gallery-nav">
<li class="toggle">Digital</li>
<li class="content">digital digital digital</li>
<li class="toggle">Logos</li>
<li class="content">logos logos logos</li>
<li class="toggle">Print</li>
<li class="content">print print print</li>
<li class="toggle">More</li>
<li class="content">more more more</li>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/). It's tried and true and should cover most of your implementation needs.